# Riemann integrability of a certain function

Tags: riemann-integration

Let $ f $ defined at $ [0,1] $ by

$$f(x)=\frac{1}{p+q}\; \;\text{if }x=\frac pq \; \text{with }\; \gcd(p,q)=1$$
and
$$f(x)=0 \; \;\text{if }\; x=0\; \text{or} \;x\notin \Bbb Q$$

I want to prove that $ f$ is Riemann integrable at $ [0,1]  \;$ and  compute $$\int_0^1f(x)dx$$

They told me to consider the set
$$E_n=\left\{x\in \Bbb Q\cap [0,1]\;\;:\;f(x)\ge \frac 1n\right\} $$ and the function $ \psi $ defined by

$$\psi(x)=\epsilon \; \text{if} \;x\notin E_n$$
and
$$\psi(x)=f(x)\; \text{if} \; x\in E_n.$$

I tried  to construct two step functions to satisfy the definition of Riemann integrability but i don't see how to use the help given.
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

I claim two things:

(i) $f$ is continuous at every irrational point in $[0,1]$ ;

(ii) $\int_0^1 f = 0$.

Notice that claim (i) tell us that $f$ is indeed (Riemann) integrable on $[0,1]$ by the Lebesgue Criterion for Riemann Integrability, beacuse $\mathbb{Q}\cap [0,1]$ has measure zero.

Try proving these claims, by first looking at [Thomae's Function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Thomae%27s_function), which is very similarly defined. (Claims (i) and (ii) also hold for Thomae's function. Can you modify the proofs to work for your function?)